# Is msbuild /t:Pack supported in full .Net framework?

Tags: msbuild, nuget, visual-studio-2017

Based on documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/msbuild-targets, it looks like msbuild now support 2 specific targets for NuGet: `Pack` and `Restore`.
I have been able to use `Restore` properly, but not `Pack`.

> error MSB4057: The target "Pack" does not exist in the project.

Is it supported for traditional .Net project or is it a .Net Core thing only?
I haven't been able to find any documentation stating it clearly.

Regarding required dependencies, I am using

```
PM> nuget help
NuGet Version: 4.1.0.2450
usage: NuGet <command> [args] [options] 
Type 'NuGet help <command>' for help on a specific command.
```

And

```
C:\Git>msbuild /version
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.1.1012.6693
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

15.1.1012.6693
```

With

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2017 
Version 15.2 (26430.12) Release
VisualStudio.15.Release/15.2.0+26430.12
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.6.01586
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is supported out of the box for "SDK-based" projects. There is no project template in VS for .NET Framework libraries using this ""new-style csproj"", but you can create a .NET Standard library project and manually change the `TargetFramework` property in the csproj file from `netstandard1.6` to `net461`. Note that the project system that is used for these types of project doesn't support many features available in classic .net projects yet (like designers for WinForms, Xaml, edmx).

The resulting project file would look like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: So the key point here is to switch to the new csproj format? So until this is supported **AS DEFAULT** by VS, there is no point to switch by hacking it, right?

Comment: yes the new format brings the integration and the property editor for NuGet properties. There's also the `NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack` NuGet package but this may not work "good enough" without adding even more  properties to the csproj that are defaulted by the "sdk-style" project.
But if you only create "logic" nuget packages this is already supported, there's just no template for it. and it's already how many libraries are built (e.g. Newtonsoft.Json)

Comment: I saw it a few times in Azure related NuGet and was wondering how it could worked. Seems clear now: I will stick with my old nuspecs as my solution contains class library projects but Asp.Net MVC and WebAPI too. I don't want to have multiple way to manage NuGet definitions in same solution.

Comment: Makes sense. but referencing "new-style" csproj files from classic projects should be supported as well, so your web app should still be able to reference this project.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I did not Google enough... this blog post clearly speaks about .Net Core only: http://blog.nuget.org/20170316/NuGet-now-fully-integrated-into-MSBuild.html

> Some of the features discussed earlier are not yet fully supported for
>   packages.config based projects such as defining nuspec metadata in
>   project files, building packages directly from a project, [...]. We are hard at work to bring full PackageReference support to
>   these project types. Our goal is to eventually make PackageReference
>   the default and move away from all other formats.

Comment: The VS 2017 version 15.2 which supports PackageReference for classic projects has already shipped. But that doesn't give pack support.